# What are some interactive resources for learning django?

Tags: django, interactive, web-development-server

I have been using interactive resources for learning Python and JavaScript like Udacity.com and codecademy.com and find this learning style the most helpful. I've gained a lot of experience with functional programming in both but have little familiarity with the structure of the web.

I'm trying to get into web-development. I have found several text-book style resources, like the django documentation, however I would rather have a project focused education. To this end I have 3 questions:

1. Is django primarily (or entirely) for web development?
2. Should I experience web development in python before experimenting with django?
3. Are there any interactive or project oriented resources for learning django?

Comment: Thank you. I was about to try HTML <br>. Is that how it's done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Django is a Web framework, so yes, it is entirely focused on Web development.
2. Ideally you should have spent some time learning Python first, yes.  But no, it doesn't need to be web development experience.
3. I would recommend starting with the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/), and then move on to the ['Getting Started with Django'](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/) video tutorials.

Comment: Is this the guy (gswd) that had a kickstarter project to create django videos?

Comment: Kenneth Love.  Yup, it's a KickStarter project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. No, Django and other wsgi frameworks provide an abstraction over `wsgi` protocol.  Learning cgi or wsgi directly, is not necessary to being successful with django
3. What is more interactive then creating a django site on your own machine while following the django tutorial?

Comment: There is a gamelike interactive tutorial for rails http://railsforzombies.org/ but there is nothing similar (that I know of for django)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  As for number 3, what I'm looking for is something with feedback built in.